# Reference for Hodge decomposition

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, real-analysis

Let $U$ be a bounded open subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$ with Lipschitz boundary, and $g \in L^2(U,\mathbb{R}^d)$ be a solenoidal vector field (i.e. $\nabla \cdot g = 0$). Then $g$ can be written in the form 
$$
g = \nabla \cdot S + \nabla h,
$$
where $h$ is harmonic and $S$ takes values in the set of skew-symmetric matrices. Does someone know of a good reference for this result?

Comment: You are describing basically the [Hodge decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Rham_cohomology#Hodge_decomposition). For Lipschitz domains the result is derived in [this AMS memoir](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1809655) (and probably elsewhere too).

Comment: Thanks for this reference. I would be even happier with a reference that only proves the statement for subsets of $\mathbb{R}^d$ (as opposed to Riemannian manifolds), and does not explicitly refer to Hodge theory or differential forms. Is there something like this somewhere?

Comment: For smooth boundaries, possibly yes, in some advanced calculus textbooks. For Lipschitz boundaries I am slightly doubtful.

Comment: Actually, it would suffice for my needs to handle the case of convex polygonal shapes, if this is of any help.

Comment: On $\mathbb R^n$ this is also called the Helmholtz decomposition - search also under this name.

Comment: It is written in Girault-Raviart's textbook on Navier Stokes for $d=2,3$.